# Status back content update acting strangely iOS13

Tags: swift, ios13

For some reason the status bar is not updating the content (.lightContent) in iOS13. It takes like a second to actually update. It is working correctly on iOS12.

I have added `View controller-based status bar appearance` in the info.plist

My Code:

```
public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override public var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    //Override all Bool

    if (self.view.backgroundColor?.isLight())! {
        return .default
    } else {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

[image: gif]

Comment: It is weird but maybe it is because of iOS 13 dark/light mode. Try overriding the user interface style.

Comment: @matt strange that it only changes the carrier and the time.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant when I said "it is weird". :) Another idea is that `viewWillAppear` may be rather late in the process. What you are doing with the navigation bar tint color is very odd; does the navigation bar have different colors for different view controllers?

Comment: I have tried adding it in other places with the same result. So I have a custom navigationBar that I add a bunch of features depending on what I specify in @IBDesignable. That's why I eventually hide the navigation bar, I was testing to see if I could change the tint and then hide it if that would stop the black being shown. I'm doing an advanced theming application for a bunch of clients and colours change based on their theming file, thats why I am doing what I am doing. I am trying to make it completely customisable for their needs, thus allowing different navigation bar colours.

Comment: The class where is came from is inherited by all the other classes that need to be themed.

Comment: OK so you would need to show a lot more code in order for use to reproduce this.

Comment: That's the problem, it's over 5 000 lines.I was hoping for a simple solution or something I was missing. Thanks for your input and help. Will comment if I fix it!

Comment: Well you see none of us are having this problem! If you cannot show us _how_ to have the problem, we cannot help you with it. And have not shown us how to have it. I do not disbelieve that this is happening for _you_, but in order to ask a question about it on Stack Overflow you need to make it happen for _me_.

Comment: @matt Update, this seems to be a simulator bug, still not sure what is causing it, but it is not happening on a physical device

Answer (score 1):

```
overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

matt commented to override the interface style, I do not have enough rep to add a comment, but this is a way to override to dark mode. Another possibility is that there is an issue with `self.view.backgroundColor?.isLight()`and your background color.

Comment: Thanks @ekrenzin, I don't think there is a problem with my `isLight()` function. It's working in other parts of the application correctly. I will try doing what you said, but I don't particularly want to force dark mode.

Comment: Added this to the appDelegate, it fixes the error, i'd rather find away to fix it without forcing darkMode. Thanks for your input though

Comment: I can reply here! I looked back through, and it seems as though you might be updating the status bar at the wrong time? If it updated before at the correct time, my guess is that the background color is being changed, and the method checks the bg color. Have you tried 'return .lightContent' without the conditional? Does it still flicker? If not, try to use a conditional that checks a non UI element.

Comment: I comment about this above, I have tried moving all the code to different times in the process, the code I posted was the last one I tried. I have tested just returning light content and it still does the same thing. Very strange

Comment: Hmmm, very strange. I'll try and think about it today and see if I can come up with a better answer. Good luck!

Comment: Update, this seems to be a simulator bug, still not sure what is causing it, but it is not happening on a physical device

Comment: very strange~ I'm glad you have got it working where it counts though.